# MYSQL: select latest record only (on left join table)

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables:

> Table1:

```
ID | Mobile Number | Name | Ordered Product| Order Date
```

Table2:

```
ID(foreign_key can be inserted multipletimes in this table) |Contacted_for | Time(timestamp)
```

I need a query to display all the data in Table1 and if the ID is present in Table 2, I need to display the last inserted record on Table2(with time) of that ID

My query is

```
select a.* , b.* FROM table1 a LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.ID=b.ID GROUP BY a.ID ORDER BY b.Time DESC
```

Here in my query when I remove Group By a.ID, it works but shows all results. But I want to show final record of table2 only(no duplicate ID records)

Thanks in advance

Comment: only you need last record?

Comment: Your question is so popular on SO it even has its own tag: [`greatest-n-per-group`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'll need some subquery's for that:

```
SELECT
    a.*, b.*
FROM
    table1 a
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT c.id, d.contacted_for, c.time
     FROM
         (SELECT
            id,
            MAX(time) time
         FROM
             table2
         GROUP BY id
         ) c
     JOIN
         table2 d
         ON c.id = d.id AND d.time = c.time
     ) b
     ON a.id = b.id
```

Comment: This is the way to go. Unfortunately in MySQL on a left join with "group by "it is undefined which of the sub-table records you get, and an order by clause doesn't change this. So you need to have a sub query.

Answer (score 7):

You can also try this way.

```
Select * from table1 a left join
(Select * from table2 where id in (select max(id) from table2 group by id) ) b on a.id=b.id
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do it is to have `CreatedAt` and `ModifiedAt` fields in every table in database. Then you just add `ORDER BY CreatedAd LIMIT 1`. Not sure if your `Time` is what I mean.

What you also have is ID. Now, if `ID` is `AutoIncremental` then job should be easy. Use `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: if i add limit 1 it will display 1 data only.. I said I need to display all the data in table1.. Thanks for your reply..

Answer (score -1):

Try this ... I hope it may works

```
select a.* , b1.* 
FROM table1 a 
LEFT JOIN table2 b1
ON ( a.ID=b1.ID)  
LEFT JOIN table2 b2
ON ( a.ID=b1.ID)  AND 
(b1.Time < b2.Time OR b1.Time = b2.Time AND b1.ID < b2.ID)
WHERE b2.ID IS NULL
GROUP BY a.ID ORDER BY b1.Time DESC
```

Comment: "I hope" ?? No it won't work, you have some serious errors in the query,

Comment: The query will work, but is not an answer to the question., because it will not display all the data of table 1.

Comment: No it doesn't, OP wants ALL data in table1 and if the ID is present table2 then the most recent entry. If the ID isn't present in table2 b2.ID will be NULL and that's the where condition so it will be excluded.