# MySQL and PHP select different row

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli

I have this table

Configuration

```
ID   Location   Position   CheckData    UpdateDT
1    House1      Floor1     20        2020-06-24 18:12:20
2    House1      Floor1     30        2020-06-24 13:54:16
3    House1      Floor2     45        2020-06-24 10:06:34  
4    House2      Roof1      70        2020-05-12 13:27:43
5    House1      Floor1     35        2020-05-12 12:20:12
```

I like to make a `select` to get from the Configuration table only the latest updated values for each "home" and "position" e.g.

```
1    House1    Floor1     20        2020-06-24 18:12:20
3    House1    Floor2     45        2020-06-24 10:06:34
4    House2    Roof1      70        2020-05-12 13:27:43
```

i have try this, but its not working, because i dont know how to add the position on it

> select * from Configuration where Location = 'house 1' order by Configuration.UpdateDT desc limit 1

and here is the php code that i have so far

```
$sqlsyntax = "SELECT * FROM `DevicesLocations`";
$resultfromsql = mysqli_query($connectionstring, $sqlsyntax);
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultfromsql) )
{
   echo $row['Location'] . " " . $row['Comments'];
   echo "<br />";
   $sql2 = "SELECT * from Configuration where location='";
   $sql2 = $sql2.$row['Location']."' order by UpdateDT desc limit 1";
   echo $sql2."<br>";
   $result2 = mysqli_query($connectionstring, $sql2);
   while( $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2) )
   {
      echo "..........".$row2['SensorPosition'] . " " . $row2['CheckData'] ;
      echo "<br />";
   }
   echo "------------------------------<br>";
}
```

Output

```
House1    first home
...... floor1 20
House2     second home
...... Roof1 70
```

Desired Output

```
House1    first home
...... floor1 20
...... floor2 45
House2     second home
...... Roof1 70
```

If i use the following `select`, how i can include the latest date?

```
SELECT * FROM `Configuration` group BY Configuration.SensorPosition
```

Comment: you can use `WHERE` like `select * from Configuration WHERE Location = "House1" order by Configuration.UpdateDT desc limit 1`

Comment: i add the code that i have so far. I want  a list so the user can select the location he want to see the data according to the latest update he have.  And for the second house?

Comment: what is result of row2?

Comment: Thank you a lot for that!!! The good think is that the user cant type any data! Data stored automatically from the device when it see moves.

Comment: It doesn't change the fact that it is still vulnerable. SQL injection is a bug in your code and it does not matter where the data comes from.

Comment: I can tell you that i am alot worried now! i will check the links you have provide me already and i will make the corrections asap.. do you have the kind to tell me what i have to change on the above code please? Thanks again!

Comment: This needs to be parameterized `$sql2.$row['Location']`

Comment: `$sql2.$row['Location']` get the value from the first select  `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultfromsql)` am i wrong? i have also include an output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216576/discussion-between-g-kal-and-dharman).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619030/mysql-join-the-most-recent-row-only https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27980305/mysql-select-latest-record-only-on-left-join-table https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44291451/mysql-join-on-the-latest-row

Answer (score 0):

I think i have found the answer. so, please correct me if i am wrong

```
SELECT m.* from Configuration m 
   left join Configuration b on 
     m.SensorPosition = b.SensorPosition and 
     m.UpdateDT < b.UpdateDT where b.UpdateDT is null
```

[I follow this link to get the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql?rq=1)